# Checking against a table before query?

Tags: sql

In the following query, how could I do a sub query to find all categories in `exp_categories` that have a `parent_id` AND all categories that are a parent, but don't have any children, then use this instead of the `AND c.parent_id != '0'`?

```
SELECT c.cat_url_title
FROM exp_channel_titles as t
LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts AS cp ON cp.entry_id = t.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_categories AS c ON cp.cat_id = c.cat_id
WHERE t.url_title = 'hummingbird'
AND c.parent_id != '0'
AND c.cat_url_title != 'latest-work'
AND c.cat_url_title != 'best-selling-images' 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Wait: `all categories that are a parent, but don't have any children`. Don't get that part... Do they have children or not?

Comment: Quick code review>> Use `<>` instead of `!=`. Also, for `c.parent_id != '0'`, is `c.parent_id` a string or int? If it's an int (and probably should be), then go with `c.parent_id <> 0`. Drop the quotes and the implied datatype conversion. I'd also move the `WHERE` statements up into the `JOIN`s, unless the filtering is appropriate in the `WHERE`. And just for cleanliness sakes, I'd go with `AND c.cat_url_title NOT IN ('latest-work','best-selling-images')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT c.cat_url_title
FROM exp_channel_titles as t
LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts AS cp ON cp.entry_id = t.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_categories AS c ON cp.cat_id = c.cat_id
WHERE t.url_title = 'hummingbird'
AND c.parent_id in (
  select id from exp_categories where parent_id is not null
  union
  select id from exp_categories where id not in (
    select parent_id from exp_categories
    )
)
AND c.cat_url_title != 'latest-work'
AND c.cat_url_title != 'best-selling-images' 
LIMIT 1
```